Why does setting a variable readonly in the outer scope prevent defining a local variable with the same name?
I've found nothing about this in all my searching.
In the code below, Bar1 acts like I'd expect a "regular" variable to act (since help declare says that -g is only "seen" in function calls): it changes value depending on the scope (outer or inner).
Bar2, being "plainly" declared, also acts like I expect (being gfhjnfd in the outer scope, and blat in the inner scope.
But Foo is a globally unchanging variable.  help declare only says "to make NAMEs readonly".  Where is this extended (and unwanted) feature documented?
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

declare -r Foo=bar
declare -g Bar1=fdhtbn
declare Bar2=gfhjnfd

X()
{
    local Foo=$1
    local Bar1=snorkel
    local Bar2=$2
    echo Foo in X = $Foo
    echo Bar1 in X = $Bar1
    echo Bar2 in X = $Bar2
}

echo Foo, above X, = $Foo
echo Bar1, above X = $Bar1
echo Bar2, above X = $Bar2
echo
X baz blat
echo
echo Foo, below X, = $Foo
echo Bar1, below X = $Bar1
echo Bar2, below X = $Bar2

$ ./test.sh
Foo, above X, = bar
Bar1, above X = fdhtbn
Bar2, above X = gfhjnfd

./test.sh: line 9: local: Foo: readonly variable
Foo in X = bar
Bar1 in X = snorkel
Bar2 in X = blat

Foo, below X, = bar
Bar1, below X = fdhtbn
Bar2, below X = gfhjnfd


Are you expecting to use local Foo to remove the read-only-ness from the outer Foo variable?  You can't do that.

@Kusalananda yes, that's what I'm expecting, since I can't find anything that says "-r implies globalness". Where's that documented?

declare -g at the global scope doesn't do anything interesting. The -g option is for declaring a named inside a function as global, as declare foo inside a function implicitly makes the variable local, just as if you had used local.

The underlying problem here is that the local keyword doesn't really create a local variable, or at least, not in the sense that you're expecting.
Per the Bash Reference Manual:

Variables local to the function may be declared with the local builtin (local variables). Ordinarily, variables and their values are shared between a function and its caller. These variables are visible only to the function and the commands it invokes. This is particularly important when a shell function calls other functions.

and

local can only be used within a function; it makes the variable name have a visible scope restricted to that function and its children.

(where boldface represents my emphasis).
In computer science terms, Bash uses dynamic scope instead of lexical scope; but from the standpoint of a typical programmer living in the year 2024, what this really means is that local doesn't create a local variable, it just temporarily modifies the global variable. Its special magic is that it automatically restores the variable's original value (and other properties) when the function returns, which is useful, but is not a full implementation of "local variables" in the sense that you expect.
So if local could override readonly, then something like this:
readonly three=3

print_three() {
  echo "$three"
}

print_four() {
  local three=4

  print_three
}

print_four

would print 4 instead of 3 — the variable three wouldn't really be readonly.

As Stéphane Chazelas points out in his answer, some shells do let local override readonly. But I would argue that this is a mistake in any shell where local has the same basic behavior as in Bash (namely, temporarily modifying a global variable instead of creating a separate local variable), and that behavior genuinely conflicts with the intention of readonly. I can only assume that their motivation was to have local variables be slightly more like true local variables, but that's not helpful so long as they're not truly local.

In your example, print_four() does not pass it's local param three to print_three(). There's no echo $1.   Thus, I'd expect it to print 3.`

Here's where I'd have expected print_four() to print 3: the code readonly three=3; print_three() { echo "three in print_three: $three"; echo "param 1 in print_three: $1"; }; print_four() { local three=4; print_three $three; }; print_four.  But that's my lexical thinking...

I don't agree with that characterisation. In bash, the manual clearly describes it as local variables being created separately and shadowing the one(s) from parent scope(s). Even in the Almquist shell (where local comes from and where local variables inherit value and attributes of the parent variable), the local variables can be seen as being copies of the parent variable, discarded upon return of the function, same as in the local variables of the Bourne shell that you get in subshells where the copy is done by fork() and discarded upon exit.

@StéphaneChazelas: Thanks for your comment! I think that both ways of looking at it are valid and useful. The way that I characterized it in this answer is more useful for intuiting its behavior, whereas the "creates a local variable" framing is more useful for understanding its overall purpose. In this case Bash's handling of readonly is being driven by behavioral considerations, so that framing seems more helpful in answering this question. But I'm not offended if you disagree. :-)

Whether readonly in one scope will prevent a variable with the same name to be declared in child scopes (in those shells that have dynamic scoping such as bash) varies between shells¹.
That came up during Austin group discussions about specifying local scope for variables in POSIX sh (an effort now abandoned as getting a consensus (on that an many other aspects) prove impossible).
In bash, that's by design and the maintainer said they wouldn't budge on that (at least not in the default environment), as it's considered there a security measure.
readonly can be used for two not fully-compatible purposes:

as a development tool to define global constants expected not to change, so you're warned when your code tries to and you can then fix your code (a bit like the const of C though here it happens at runtime).
as a security measure in restricted shells (a very poor sandboxing security feature) where some special variables such as $PATH, $HISTFILE (though an administrator wanting to provide a restricted shell environment would likely want to set more variables read-only such as LD_PRELOAD, PERL5LIB...) would need to remain read-only to prevent users bypassing the restrictions.

In bash, modifications of $PATH (which has the only allowed commands) in restricted shells relies on the readonly attribute, so it's important those variables cannot be modified (including their list of attributes or scopes) even in child scopes.
In zsh, $PATH and a few other variables (including LD_PRELOAD, but not PERL5LIB, PYTHONPATH...) are restricted, but not via the read-only attribute, so readonly can be used reliably for the first usage mentioned above, but that means that if your restricted-environment has some commands written in perl or python, users may be able to bypass restrictions via the PERL5LIB/PYTHONPATH environment variables for instance and making those readonly won't help as the users can do typeset +r PERL5LIB to remove that readonly attribute or shadow it in a child scope with a non-readonly one.

¹ See List of shells that support `local` keyword for defining local variables for more details about local scope in various POSIX-like shells.

This is documented under local in
www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Builtins

The return status is zero unless local is used outside a function, an
invalid name is supplied, or name is a readonly variable.

I do find this surprising, as the first sentence there says:

For each argument, a local variable named name is created, and
assigned value.

That implies a new variable is created with scope restricted to that function. There is an argument that a global constant should be reliably preserved.

And in the -r subsection of the declare section on the same page: "These names cannot then be assigned values by subsequent assignment statements or unset."  Presumably those "subsequent assignment statements" means even those in inner scopes?

You also can't unset a readonly variable, even though that might be seen as conceptually different from modifying the value (compare with e.g. removing a file vs. writing to it). In a way, preventing the variable from being shadowed by another one with the same name seems to fit the same idea. Especially given how variable scoping works. A function F expecting to be called from the main level and using a readonly variable defined there could be made to see another variable instead if called through G where the same name was redefined to shadow the main-level readonly one.

@ilkkachu "A function F expecting to be called from the main level and using a readonly variable defined there".  To clarify: where is "there"?  Do you mean "defined in 'main'" or "defined in F"?

@RonJohn, expecting to be called from the main level and expecting to see a variable defined there in the main level

@ilkkachu well, sure.  That's risk when -- and point of -- using global variables.  Say, for example, I've got a large global array named X in script blarge, and a similarly named large global array named X in script blotto.  The data in the arrays are different because, in this example, they are different sets of server names, IP addresses, etc.  They both call the same function process_servers(), which assumes a global array named X.

@ilkkachu (Of course, that's just an off the cuff example, not something I'd actually do.)

@RonJohn: Just making sure . . . you are aware that local in Bash (and in all similar shells) uses dynamic local scope rather than the lexical scope familiar from most programming languages? (That is -- you're aware that x=3 ; f() { echo "$x" ; } ; g() { local x=4; f ; } ; g prints 4 rather than 3?)

@RonJohn: No -- in most languages the equivalent code would print 3, because the local variable x in function g has no effect on function f. (That is: in most languages, the equivalent of local declares a completely new variable, with no effect on any existing variable with the same name.) Dynamic local scope isn't unheard-of -- aside from shell languages, early dialects of Lisp also used it, and Perl supports both kinds of scope -- but it's definitely not the norm.

@ruakh hmmm.  That parameterless call to f in g slipped by me.  So... no, apparently I didn't know that.  WTF came up with that cockamamie and very brain dead idea?

@ruakh, ksh is an outlier here, though; it actually has lexical scoping. Somewhat significantly, considering that otherwise Bash has borrowed nearly everything from ksh.

@RonJohn: Re: "no, apparently I didn't know that": OK, cool. I think that explains why you were expecting a different behavior. I've posted an answer that attacks that directly. :-)   Re: "WTF came up with that cockamamie and very brain dead idea?": I don't know, but it's genuinely much easier to support dynamic local scope than lexical scope, especially given how dynamic Bash is in general. (Bash even has mechanisms to let you refer to a variable whose name is stored in a different variable!)

@ilkkachu: Good to know, thank you!

@ruakh "(Bash even has mechanisms to let you refer to a variable whose name is stored in a different variable!"  I saw that, but just thought "reference pointers".

@ruakh, an interpreter that runs/can run each input line immediately has to be able to find the variables by name just because that's what the source code has anyway, so it's not a big step to do the indirect access through another variable. Note that references by name aren't all that wonderful either; they have the problem that you can't pass a reference to an arbitrary outer level variable into a function, since the function can have a local with the same name that then "hijacks" the reference. x=123; p=x; foo() { local x=999; echo ${!p}; }; foo prints 999.

@ilkkachu: Yes, exactly. :-)
